# How do you know when a variable/property has been closed over?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

Given an expression like:

```
Int32 five = 5;

Express(num => num == five);
```

where `Express` is something like

```
void Express(Expression<Predicate<Int32>> predicatesGonnaPredicate)
{
    ....
}
```

When parsing the expression above, how would I determine programmatically that five has been closed over? I can think of a ton of hack ways to do it, but what there must be some proper means of identifying this?

Comment: I cannot make heads nor tails of this code. What is `five` and why is `number` not used in the lambda?

Comment: Also: values are not closed over in the first place. **Outer variables** are closed over. (Note that if the code is in a class then "this" counts as an outer variable even though it is not a variable.)

Comment: Why do you want to know that? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Serialize an expression to XML. If the field/property has been closed over, then I should attempt to evaluate that expression and then serialize it as a constant rather than transmitting useless closure information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want replace all sub-expression that don't depend on the parameters on the lambda with their values, you can use `PartialEval` from Matt Warren's article [*Building an IQueryable Provider - Part III*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx).

For example, in your case the result will be an expression `num => num == 5`.

Comment: You know what, I JUST JUST figured that out. You can evaluate anything that doesn't contain a parameter, so I just need to verify there are no parameters and if not I can evaluate locally. Thanks for the answer!